# Django + Gunicorn + nginx yields very poor performance. Can't get even 8 qps

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I am using nginx + gunicorn for serving a django app and have deployed it on EC2 (m1.small instance).

I have this view:

```
def hi(request):
    return HttpResponse('hi', content_type='text/plain')
```

mapped to url `/hi/`. So it basically just returns `hi` at `[myurl]/hi`.

Now when I load test this domain (`[myurl]/hi`) from `loader.io`, this doesn't even pass the **250 clients over 30 secs** test. (Approx 8 requests per second)

[This is](http://pastebin.com/JZ6iNF7K) (part of) my nginx access.log file. It basically just gives `499`s after few `200`s. (Timeout in loader.io is set to 10 secs)

I must be doing something seriously wrong. How do I find out?

I profiled it using `yet-another-django-profiler` and following is the output:
[image]

I deployed this django app on Elastic Beanstalk (which uses Apache server) too (m3.large instance), and there too I get terrible performance. 
My middleware as of now is:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    # 'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',
    # 'yet_another_django_profiler.middleware.ProfilerMiddleware',
    # 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    # 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    # 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

Earlier none of it was commented out. When I commented out these 9 lines, I got a performance boost. Now I can get 60 qps out of this app. But I think I am doing more blunders and that it can scale further.

Comment: My first guess would be that you have misconfigured the systems.  For example maybe you have [not specified enough worker threads](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/design.html#how-many-workers) for gunicorn.  If you've already got that covered, you should start digging in to where your bottleneck lies - CPU, RAM, disk or network.  Providing some CPU and response times while you are under load (e.g. from `vmstat` and looking at request/response times from `tcpdump`) would help at this point.

Comment: 1. What is the command you're using to launch gunicorn? 2. What does your settings file look like (the middleware in particular)? 3. What else is running on that server?

Comment: @Seth: Yes, middleware was part of the problem. There is nothing more running on the server. Also I am launching gunicorn [with this script](http://pastebin.com/DezHbyiC).

Comment: Using a unix socket for gunicorn could speed things up as it saves turning data into packets and back again

Answer (score 2):

This is just a stab in the dark without more to go on, and I don't have enought reputation to comment on your original question: I noticed that your gunicorn startup script has

```
--log-level=debug
```

If you have debug level logging (in gunicorn and especially in the Django project) it would explain why the performance was increased by commenting out the middleware and why you would keep getting degraded performance out of a different deployment architecture.

Debug level logging outputs A LOT of information.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue about what you may did wrong but may I suggest you to test again using uWSGI instead of Gunicorn ? According to many benchmarks, uWSGI seems to provides better performance than Gunicorn and if the performance doesn't change significantly you'll be able to focus your investigation on nginx or EC2 configurations.
I don't want to proselytize, just encouraging you to find through a process of elimination.

Hope it will help !